# Site works in locale but not in remote

Tags: 7

I uploaded my site and the database on the remote server; the site is working in locale, but on the remote I get the following error.

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'queryfdu_drupal7.watchdog' doesn't exist: INSERT INTO {watchdog} (uid, type, message, variables, severity, link, location, referer, hostname, timestamp) VALUES (:db_insert_placeholder_0, :db_insert_placeholder_1, :db_insert_placeholder_2, :db_insert_placeholder_3, :db_insert_placeholder_4, :db_insert_placeholder_5, :db_insert_placeholder_6, :db_insert_placeholder_7, :db_insert_placeholder_8, :db_insert_placeholder_9); Array ( [:db_insert_placeholder_0] => 0 [:db_insert_placeholder_1] => domain [:db_insert_placeholder_2] => Domain access failed to load during phase: bootstrap include. Please check your settings.php file and site configuration. [:db_insert_placeholder_3] => N; [:db_insert_placeholder_4] => 3 [:db_insert_placeholder_5] => [:db_insert_placeholder_6] => [:db_insert_placeholder_7] => [:db_insert_placeholder_8] => 122.175.149.244 [:db_insert_placeholder_9] => 1434778958 ) в функции dblog_watchdog() (строка 160 в файле /home/queryfdu/public_html/drupal/modules/dblog/dblog.module).

The watchdog table exists in the database.

How can I fix this problem? What could be causing it?

Answer (score 0):

That is fairly straight forward. The watchdog table - the system log for Drupal - is missing from your production environment. The real question is really how are you deploying your site. Whatever method you are using doesn't seem to be working properly. If this is a brand new site it would be better to deploy as an install and add all of your customizations as [Features](https://www.drupal.org/project/features).

Comment: All the table is present in my database but that error is coming

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your `settings.php` you have added a table_prefix but the database doesn't seem to have it.

Remove the table prefix option in your `settings.php` and everything should work fine.

Look for

```
$databases['default']['default'] = array(
  'driver' => 'mysql',
  'database' => 'databasename',
  'username' => 'username',
  'password' => 'password',
  'host' => 'localhost',
  'prefix' => '',  // <-- remove your prefix here
);
```

Comment: Or simply, the prefix is the wrong one. In this case, should not the error be for other tables as well? It is strange the error appears just for a table.